# Check if a string contains a substring in SQL Server 2005, using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I've a string, `@mainString = 'CATCH ME IF YOU CAN'`. I want to check whether the word `ME` is inside `@mainString`.

How do I check if a string has a specific substring in SQL?

Answer (score 439, accepted):

[`CHARINDEX()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) searches for a substring within a larger string, and returns the position of the match, or 0 if no match is found

```
if CHARINDEX('ME',@mainString) > 0
begin
    --do something
end
```

*Edit* or from daniels answer, if you're wanting to find a word (and not subcomponents of words), your `CHARINDEX` call would look like:

```
CHARINDEX(' ME ',' ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@mainString,',',' '),'.',' ') + ' ')
```

(Add more recursive REPLACE() calls for any other punctuation that may occur)

Comment: s/recursive/nested/ -- "recursive" would be if `REPLACE` called itself; "nested" is when the result of a function call is immediately passed to another function.

Comment: Would the 'ME' be case sensitive in SQL or would you also have to do an if statement for 'Me' and 'me'?

Comment: @a.powell - depends on the collation's involved. You can always force it within this test if you need it one way or the other. E.g. compare `select CHARINDEX('ME' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS,'Home')` and `select CHARINDEX('ME' collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,'Home')`. (In collations, `CS` stands for Case Sensitive and I'm sure you can work out `CI`).

Comment: @VincePanuccio - T-SQL's *string* processing is notoriously weak. SQL's strength is in set-based operations. In this case (wanting to do string processing, and something where a regex would be an obvious solution), it's more a case of them picking the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 134):

You can just use wildcards in the predicate (after IF, WHERE or ON):

```
@mainstring LIKE '%' + @substring + '%'
```

or in this specific case

```
' ' + @mainstring + ' ' LIKE '% ME[., ]%'
```

(Put the spaces in the quoted string if you're looking for the whole word, or leave them out if ME can be part of a bigger word).

Comment: If you're looking for word matches (your second example), you'd need to a) add a space before and after @mainString (so you can match first or last word), and b) remove punctuation

Comment: This is better than CHARINDEX() for me because in my particular case, I cannot execute the CHARINDEX() function due to limited permissions.

Comment: (Just don't forget to prefix all your string constants with `N` if your column is an `nvarchar`, otherwise you get per-row conversions)

Comment: This may be obvious, it seems like the `LIKE` operator supports RegEx, but `LIKE` operator is [*not* RegEx per se](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9076427/1175496); this technique [uses wildcard characters as literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals) when it searches for `'% ME[., ]%'`, the `[., ]` part is wildcard character group which checks for an optional period, comma, or space after the word "ME". Thanks!