# Using RegEx in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking how to replace/encode text using RegEx based on RegEx settings/params below:

```
RegEx.IgnoreCase = True     
RegEx.Global = True     
RegEx.Pattern = "[^a-z\d\s.]+"
```

I have seen some examples on RegEx, but confused as to how to apply it the same way in SQL Server. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Hi take a look at this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server-2005-2008

Comment: There's also a fine **TSQL** **+ Windows API** solution at [Robyn Page and Phil Factor's](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/) that relies on [VBScript.RegExp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee236360%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) class, which, I belieave, is shipped on every Windows version since Windows 2000.

Comment: If you absolutely positively need RegEx via TSQL, an option for SQL Server 2016 and above is to [use R services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql/46536661#46536661).

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You do not need to interact with managed code, as you can use [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample(Field varchar(50), Result varchar(50))
GO
INSERT INTO #Sample (Field, Result) VALUES ('ABC123 ', 'Do not match')
INSERT INTO #Sample (Field, Result) VALUES ('ABC123.', 'Do not match')
INSERT INTO #Sample (Field, Result) VALUES ('ABC123&', 'Match')
SELECT * FROM #Sample WHERE Field LIKE '%[^a-z0-9 .]%'
GO
DROP TABLE #Sample
```

As your expression ends with `+` you can go with `'%[^a-z0-9 .][^a-z0-9 .]%'`

**EDIT**:
To make it clear: SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions without managed code. Depending on the situation, the `LIKE` operator can be an option, but it lacks the flexibility that regular expressions provides.

Comment: @MikeYoung, you're right. This answer incorrectly addresses the `+` quantifier as `{1,2}` when it should take it as `{1, }`. Surprisingly, this worked to the OP.

Comment: This won't works in sql server since it doesn't support regex.

Comment: @VVN, `LIKE` is not regex (it's a more limited pattern-matching syntax), so the lack of regex support doesn't mean that this won't work.

Comment: @RubensFarias wouldn't it be nice to update the answer in light of comments from @mike-young?

Answer (score 14):

[Regular Expressions In SQL Server Databases Implementation Use](https://study.com/academy/lesson/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-databases-implementation-use.html)

Regular Expression -    Description 
**.**   Match any one character 
*   Match any character 
**+**   Match at least one instance of the expression before 
**^**   Start at beginning of line 
**$**   Search at end of line 
**<**   Match only if word starts at this point 
**>**    Match only if word stops at this point 
**\n**  Match a line break 
**[]**  Match any character within the brackets 
**[^...]**  Matches any character not listed after the ^ 
**[ABQ]%**  The string must begin with either the letters A, B, or Q and can be of any length 
**[AB][CD]%**   The string must have a length of two or more and which must begin with A or B and have C or D as the second character 
**[A-Z]%**  The string can be of any length and must begin with any letter from A to Z 
**[A-Z0-9]%**   The string can be of any length and must start with any letter from A to Z or numeral from 0 to 9 
**[^A-C]%** The string can be of any length but cannot begin with the letters A to C 
**%[A-Z]**  The string can be of any length and must end with any of the letters from A to Z 
**%[%$#@]%**    The string can be of any length and must contain at least one of the special characters enclosed in the bracket

Comment: I am confused by this post.  Not all of the above are supported by SQL Server LIKE. But some of them are.  Is this a mixture of LIKE expressions and standard regex regular expressions?  e.g. < and > and ^ and $ for start and end of line.

Comment: @Zeek2 this answer is misleading. `LIKE` (or `PATINDEX` for that matter) only supports the wildcard matches listed [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments), which are just `%, [], [^], _`.

Comment: This is very misleading and unclear. Please clarify where these apply, and what restrictions there are.

Comment: I have just explaining how Regular Expression use each expression.

Comment: @RaviMakwana Yes, but your answer is incorrect. This is fine for languages that have regular expressions implemented, but TSQL does not.

Answer (score 13):

You will have to build a CLR procedure that provides regex functionality, as [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/) illustrates.

Their example function uses VB.NET:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Server
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Collections 'the IEnumerable interface is here  


Namespace SimpleTalk.Phil.Factor
    Public Class RegularExpressionFunctions
        'RegExIsMatch function
        <SqlFunction(IsDeterministic:=True, IsPrecise:=True)> _
        Public Shared Function RegExIsMatch( _
                                            ByVal pattern As SqlString, _
                                            ByVal input As SqlString, _
                                            ByVal Options As SqlInt32) As SqlBoolean
            If (input.IsNull OrElse pattern.IsNull) Then
                Return SqlBoolean.False
            End If
            Dim RegExOption As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegExOptions
            RegExOption = Options
            Return RegEx.IsMatch(input.Value, pattern.Value, RegExOption)
        End Function
    End Class      ' 
End Namespace
```

...and is installed in SQL Server using the following SQL (replacing '%'-delimted variables by their actual equivalents:

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE

IF EXISTS ( SELECT   1
            FROM     sys.objects
            WHERE    object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.RegExIsMatch') ) 
   DROP FUNCTION dbo.RegExIsMatch
go

IF EXISTS ( SELECT   1
            FROM     sys.assemblies asms
            WHERE    asms.name = N'RegExFunction ' ) 
   DROP ASSEMBLY [RegExFunction]

CREATE ASSEMBLY RegExFunction 
           FROM '%FILE%'
GO

CREATE FUNCTION RegExIsMatch
   (
    @Pattern NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Options int
   )
RETURNS BIT
AS EXTERNAL NAME 
   RegExFunction.[SimpleTalk.Phil.Factor.RegularExpressionFunctions].RegExIsMatch
GO

--a few tests
---Is this card a valid credit card?
SELECT dbo.RegExIsMatch ('^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$','4241825283987487',1)
--is there a number in this string
SELECT dbo.RegExIsMatch( '\d','there is 1 thing I hate',1)
--Verifies number Returns 1
DECLARE @pattern VARCHAR(255)
SELECT @pattern ='[a-zA-Z0-9]\d{2}[a-zA-Z0-9](-\d{3}){2}[A-Za-z0-9]'
SELECT  dbo.RegExIsMatch (@pattern, '1298-673-4192',1),
        dbo.RegExIsMatch (@pattern,'A08Z-931-468A',1),
        dbo.RegExIsMatch (@pattern,'[A90-123-129X',1),
        dbo.RegExIsMatch (@pattern,'12345-KKA-1230',1),
        dbo.RegExIsMatch (@pattern,'0919-2893-1256',1)
```

Comment: This is in Classic ASP, does it support?  I think CLR is only for .NET functions, right?

Comment: CLR procedures are installed into the SQL Server environment and can be invoked like any other stored procedure or user-defined function, so if Classic ASP can invoke a stored procedure or user-defined function, it can invoke a CLR procedure.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20902268)

Comment: Thanks @FedericoklezCulloca.  This was an old answer and I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: @mwigdahl thanks for that. I see it's old, but it popped up in a review queue :)

Answer (score 12):

Slightly modified version of [Julio's answer.](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/)

```
-- MS SQL using VBScript Regex
-- select dbo.RegexReplace('aa bb cc','($1) ($2) ($3)','([^\s]*)\s*([^\s]*)\s*([^\s]*)')
-- $$ dollar sign, $1 - $9 back references, $& whole match

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RegexReplace]
(   -- these match exactly the parameters of RegExp
    @searchstring varchar(4000),
    @replacestring varchar(4000),
    @pattern varchar(4000)
)
RETURNS varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @objRegexExp int, 
        @objErrorObj int,
        @strErrorMessage varchar(255),
        @res int,
        @result varchar(4000)

    if( @searchstring is null or len(ltrim(rtrim(@searchstring))) = 0) return null
    set @result=''
    exec @res=sp_OACreate 'VBScript.RegExp', @objRegexExp out
    if( @res <> 0) return '..VBScript did not initialize'
    exec @res=sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'Pattern', @pattern
    if( @res <> 0) return '..Pattern property set failed'
    exec @res=sp_OASetProperty @objRegexExp, 'IgnoreCase', 0
    if( @res <> 0) return '..IgnoreCase option failed'
    exec @res=sp_OAMethod @objRegexExp, 'Replace', @result OUT,
         @searchstring, @replacestring
    if( @res <> 0) return '..Bad search string'
    exec @res=sp_OADestroy @objRegexExp
    return @result
END
```

You'll need Ole Automation Procedures turned on in SQL:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options',1; 
go
reconfigure; 
go
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1; 
go
reconfigure; 
go
sp_configure 'show advanced options',0; 
go
reconfigure;
go
```

Comment: BTW, it's much faster to destroy and recreate the regex object than to cache and reuse it.  We ran 10,000 comparisons with significantly higher numbers reusing the object.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * from SOME_TABLE where NAME like '%[^A-Z]%'
```

Or some other expression instead of A-Z

Comment: How can I check for email validation using the above method ?

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to @mwigdahl's answer, you can also implement a .NET CLR in C#, with code such as;

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using RX = System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
 [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
 public static SqlString Regex(string input, string regex)
 {
  var match = RX.Regex.Match(input, regex).Groups[1].Value;
  return new SqlString (match);
 }
}
```

Installation instructions can be found [here](https://blog.dotnetframework.org/2019/12/17/regular-expression-clr-udf-in-sql-server/)