# Splitting up tags in data explorer posts

Tags: sql, sql-server, dataexplorer

I'm wanting to make a query which will list the tags ordered by the most unanswered questions (which have that tag), however as the tags are stored as space delimited `varchar` and as I understand it SQL Server ([which StackExchange uses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10370/245827)) doesn't have a function to split a string, I'm a bit unsure on how to proceed. I wrote this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tags from Posts WHERE AnswerCount = 0;
```

Which correctly returns the tags, however they're all grouped by post:

[image: Results]

I've looked around a lot but [every result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x) I find has creating a function as a solution to splitting the tags up, but you can't create functions on dataexchange so that isn't possible. Is there another way to get all the tags into one column?

Comment: It would be easy if you have a tag table taken from splitting them up by regexp.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server

Comment: Do you have a separate tag table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes but there's no relationship between it and the posts table as far as I can tell

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265460/query-to-get-tags-for-a-user-from-sede, the relation between posts and tags is in posttags  table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an inefficient join using `like`:

```
select t.TagName, count(p.Tags)
from Tags t left join
     Posts p
     on p.Tags like '%' + t.TagName + '%'
where p.AnswerCount = 0
group by t.TagName;
```

You should really use a separate junction table, `PostTags` with one row per post and per tag on that post.  This type of query would be much, much simpler.  SQL has a nice built-in mechanism for storing lists.  It is not a string.  It is called a table.  You should use it, if you have the choice.

Comment: With a slight tweak to the names and removing the spaces, this worked perfectly, thanks a lot!