# Formatting the SQL query result based on a pattern

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql

I have got a table that contains deferent type of date formats:

```
########
DateTime
########
10/05/2015
11/05/2015
1/5/2015
01/5/2014
```

Now my question is that How can I select all the rows based on this pattern `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}` the format the result with this pattern `\d{4}/\d{2}/\{2}`?
The first one is `dd/mm/yyyy` and I would like the result be `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: Sql server doesn't support regex but some pattern matching so you can't do what you want with regex. Unless you use a CLR

Comment: @JorgeCampos it seems SQL Server can support Regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server

Comment: Like I said it is just pattern matching, you can't use it to do your replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Dates VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
('10/05/2015'),
('11/05/2015'),
('1/5/2015'),
('01/5/2014')
```

### Query

The following query will convert all the values to proper sql server date data type.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,
       RIGHT('0000' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(Dates , '/','.'),1),4)
     + RIGHT('00'   + PARSENAME(REPLACE(Dates , '/','.'),2),2)
     + RIGHT('00'   + PARSENAME(REPLACE(Dates , '/','.'),3),2)
      )
FROM @TABLE
```

### Result

```
2015-05-10
2015-05-11
2015-05-01
2014-05-01
```

Once you have got the values in well-formatted sql server date type, you can extend the query to get the required output `yyyy/mm/dd` by doing the following:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
      CONVERT(DATE,
       RIGHT('0000' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(Dates , '/','.'),1),4)
     + RIGHT('00'   + PARSENAME(REPLACE(Dates , '/','.'),2),2)
     + RIGHT('00'   + PARSENAME(REPLACE(Dates , '/','.'),3),2)
      ), 111)
FROM @TABLE
```

### Result

```
2015/05/10
2015/05/11
2015/05/01
2014/05/01
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I you don't need to use regular expressions. A simple [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) should suffice.

`... WHERE DateTime LIKE "__/__/____" ...`