# Select SQL Non numeric Values

Tags: sql-server

I need to select just the rows within a sql table which contain no numerical values whatsoever, here's an example table:

```
AddressLine1
-------------
59 Prospect Road
Rose House
24 St. Pauls Place
1 Oxford Avenue
9 Stonecross Road
65 Wood Common
19 Falcon Close
Thorn House
16 Poplars Close
52 Coombes Road
12 Brinsmead
14 Meadow Close
15 Rowlatt Drive
```

In this example I would just be looking for "Rose House" and "Thorn House" rows to be returned.

Any suggestion on the code I should be using would be gratefully received.

Comment: You can consider using regular expressions, some examples you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server) on StackOverflow

Comment: Hi @adam-haycok , ah ... better formatting ... ah ... 2 thumbs up | pat in the back | high 5

Comment: Some answers were given but the better option would be to split it up in two columns: AddressNumber and AddressName.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
select * from tab
where AddressLine1 not like '%[0-9]%'
```

try this

Comment: You are Welcome @Adam

Comment: Using this query I am not able to get non numeric values that have an alpha character in the middle of the value

Answer (score 11):

I think the actual answer should be:

```
select * from tab where AddressLine1 like '%[^0-9]%'
```

According to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

This is the way:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME, '^-?[0-9.]+$');
```

This also excludes values which contain decimals.