# Using regex to extract everything until specific symbol double occurrence

Tags: c#, json, regex, string

I have the following statement:

```
column1==1 && 'column2'=='value' || year == 2006 || ('column2'=='value1' && 'column2'!='value2')
```

which is pass to me like the `JSON` below:

```
{
    "type": "ExpressionStatement",
    "expression": {
        "type": "LogicalExpression",
        "operator": "||",
        "left": {
            "type": "LogicalExpression",
            "operator": "||",
            "left": {
                "type": "LogicalExpression",
                "operator": "&&",
                "left": {
                    "type": "BinaryExpression",
                    "operator": "==",
                    "left": {
                        "type": "Identifier",
                        "name": "column1"
                    },
                    "right": {
                        "type": "Literal",
                        "value": 1,
                        "raw": "1"
                    }
                },
                "right": {
                    "type": "BinaryExpression",
                    "operator": "==",
                    "left": {
                        "type": "Literal",
                        "value": "column2",
                        "raw": "'column2'"
                    },
                    "right": {
                        "type": "Literal",
                        "value": "value",
                        "raw": "'value'"
                    }
                }
            },
            "right": {
                "type": "BinaryExpression",
                "operator": "==",
                "left": {
                    "type": "Identifier",
                    "name": "year"
                },
                "right": {
                    "type": "Literal",
                    "value": 2006,
                    "raw": "2006"
                }
            }
        },
        "right": {
            "type": "LogicalExpression",
            "operator": "&&",
            "left": {
                "type": "BinaryExpression",
                "operator": "==",
                "left": {
                    "type": "Literal",
                    "value": "column2",
                    "raw": "'column2'"
                },
                "right": {
                    "type": "Literal",
                    "value": "value1",
                    "raw": "'value1'"
                }
            },
            "right": {
                "type": "BinaryExpression",
                "operator": "!=",
                "left": {
                    "type": "Literal",
                    "value": "column2",
                    "raw": "'column2'"
                },
                "right": {
                    "type": "Literal",
                    "value": "value2",
                    "raw": "'value2'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to extract from this `JSON` string, only the binary expression operands. For example, for `column1==1` I need only this part of the `JSON` string:

```
"left": {
    "type": "Identifier",
    "name": "column1"
},
"right": {
    "type": "Literal",
    "value": 1,
    "raw": "1"
}
```

Having that string I can get the column name and the comparison value. As the `JSON` format string is consistent, I can use [zero-width positive lookbehind assertion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#grouping_constructs) and check for `"type": "BinaryExpression",` value. Then I need to get all data to the second `}`.

Is there a way to say with regex to get everything to the second occurrence of `}`?

Note:

1. I know it will be better to use some `JSON` to `string` parser, but I am not allowed (I am working in the context of SQL Server).
2. I know in SQL Server 2016 there is native JSON support, but some of the database are on earlier version.
3. I need pure regex solution, as in the context of the T-SQL I am not able to use .net like [this one for example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: However, TSQL has no regex support. See [Using RegEx in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server). You may use very limited *wildcard* patterns. I re-tagged the quesiton.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have implemented several SQL CLR regex functions. I have regex  replace, regex matches, regex split, etc. You can check this for more information - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx

Comment: Ok, but you did not mention it in the question. I put the regex tag back then. So, what have you tried?

Comment: If you use regexes, I guess Binary expression is always having left/right. Why not using that information?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have try something like this `(?i)(?<="BinaryExpression")[^\}]+[^\}]+` but it stops the match to the first occurrence of `}`

Comment: And how can you be sure you do not have `}` inside a string literal? You will have to match the string literals, too. And you may use capturing to *capture* the part of the pattern, to get rid of the lookbehind.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But let's say I replace all `}` symbols that are encapsulated with double quotes with some special character. Then, I can look only for second occurrence  of `}`.

Comment: This seems to work `(?i)(?<="BinaryExpression")[^\}]+.[^\}]+`.

Comment: Cool, then use `(?i)(?<="BinaryExpression")[^}]+}[^}]+` if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\"type\": \"BinaryExpression\",\s*(\".+\": +\"?.+\"?,?\s*)*(\".+\": \{\s*(\".+\": +\"?.+\"?,?\s*)+\},?\s*)+
```

Seems to work okay. Explanation:

`\"type\": \"BinaryExpression\",\s*` Find text `"type": Binary Expression" followed by some number of whitespaces

`(\".+\": +\"?.+\"?,?\s*)*` Find string of format `"something" : "something"` with an optional `,` at the end. As there might be any number of those after Binary Expression, we add * at the end. Also, as some attributes do not have `""` around them, the second qutation marks are optional. Once again followed by some whitespaces

`(\".+\": {\s*` string of format `"Something: {" whitespaces

`(\".+\": +\"?.+\"?,?\s*)+` content of format `"something": "else"` where second quotation marks are optional. As there are many lines of this type, we follow this with `+`

`},?\s*)+` those lines have to end with `}`, then an optional coma.

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/IAgV0e/1