# Regular expression for time format

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

I have time format like hh:mm ss in database table.
I have written a query to get those values from column.

```
declare @reg nvarchar(100)
set @reg = '^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$'
 select time from table1 where time = @reg
```

However, its not showing me results. How to get the results?

Edit:
Sample data(here is what I want to find from colum):

```
23:36 26
08:55 46
```

Here is what I want to change in that column:

```
23:36:26
08:55:46
```

Comment: please post sample data and expected results...

Comment: `SQL SERVER` does not support `regex`

Comment: Try to use  time LIKE reg instead of  time = reg ?

Comment: SQL Server already has a `time` type. Why are you looking for a regex at all?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that statement? Why don't you just use a `time` field, or store a proper time string by replacing ` ` with `:` ? Why the regex? Does `time` contain *non*-time strings?

Comment: I have 1Million time records in this format in the column (in a table). How can I resolve all these by hard coding? Also, time format type is char –

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using strings instead of the appropriate type, `time`. The only real solution is to fix the field type.

To convert the data, you don't need a regex, just replace  with `:` before casting, eg :

```
select cast(replace(time,' ',':') as time)
```

Executing :

```
select cast(replace('08:55 46',' ',':') as time)
```

Returns a time value of `08:55:46`

You might be tempted to cast `time` again to a string using the same command, eg: `cast(cast(replace(time,' ',':') as time) as nvarchar(8))` but that won't fix the wrong type issue. You'll be forced to parse the text into a time again each time you want to send it to the client or perform time arithmetic.

If you want to use a time variable or time parameter, just specify the appropriate type, eg :

```
declare @myParam time ='23:12:34'
```

Or

```
Create Procedure MyProc (@myTimeParam time)
...
```

Comment: I have 1Million time records in this format in the column (in a table). How can I resolve all these by hard coding? Alos, time format type is char

Comment: Thanks for the clue: Update DPUCID01
set time2 = replace(time2, ' ', ':')
WHERE time2 like '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]'

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9076427/4627980). It seems SQL SERVER does not support pure regex, you must change your query to something like this:

```
declare @reg nvarchar(100)
set @reg = '[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'
select time from table1 where time like @reg
```