# Query city names starting and ending with vowels

Tags: sql

I wrote this code (db2) and it works just fine, but I'm wondering, is there a shorter way to write this?

```
Select Distinct city
From   station
Where  city Like 'A%a'
       Or city Like 'A%e'
       Or city Like 'A%i'
       Or city Like 'A%o'
       Or city Like 'A%u'
       Or city Like 'E%a'
       Or city Like 'E%e'
       Or city Like 'E%i'
       Or city Like 'E%o'
       Or city Like 'E%u'
       Or city Like 'I%a'
       Or city Like 'I%e'
       Or city Like 'I%i'
       Or city Like 'I%o'
       Or city Like 'I%u'
       Or city Like 'O%a'
       Or city Like 'O%e'
       Or city Like 'O%i'
       Or city Like 'O%o'
       Or city Like 'O%u'
       Or city Like 'U%a'
       Or city Like 'U%e'
       Or city Like 'U%i'
       Or city Like 'U%o'
       Or city Like 'U%u';
```

Comment: `Where City Like '[AEIOU]%[AEIOU]'`

Comment: Siyual, I think he needs this instead - LIKE '[AEIOU]%[aeiou]'

Answer (score 5):

I am not a DB2 expert but this should be fairly portable:

```
WHERE LEFT(city,1) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')
  AND RIGHT(city,1) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

You may want to normalize it all to upper case to avoid problems with cities that for some reason start with a lower case letter or end with an upper case letter.

```
WHERE UPPER(LEFT(city,1)) IN ('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')
  AND LOWER(RIGHT(city,1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REGEXP` in **MySQL** to operate ***Regular Expression***

```
SELECT DISTINCT city 
FROM station 
WHERE city REGEXP '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$';
```

For people who don't familiar with Regular Expression

```
^[aeiou]    // Start with a vowel
.*          // Any characters at any times
[aeiou]$    // End with a vowel
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be answerable in SQL Server in 3 lines with an AND clause-

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM *TableName* WHERE
(city like 'a%' or city like 'e%' or city like 'i%' or city like 'o%' or city like 'u%') 
AND 
(city like '%a' or city like '%e' or city like '%i' or city like '%o' or city like '%u');
```

...

Also, you can use Regex in case of MySQL as-

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM   station
WHERE  city RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*[aeiouAEIOU]$'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in DB2, but I think you can use a regular expression in your WHERE LIKE.

Check the documentation:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html

```
Example:
Select Distinct city
From   station
Where  REGEXP_LIKE(city,'[aeiou].*[aeiou]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions in your LIKE clause. Look at the example here [Using RegEx in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server)

In Sql server your LIKE clause might look like this.

```
LIKE '[AEIOU]%[aeiou]'
```

In DB2 the syntax is slightly different. Look few examples down on this page.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301stolze/0301stolze.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `substr` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION WHERE SUBSTR(CITY,1,1) IN('A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u') 
and SUBSTR(CITY,-1,1) IN('A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY,'^[^aeiouAEIOU].*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in Oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY,'^[^aeiouAEIOU].*');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city from station where REGEXP_LIKE(city,'[aeiou]$');
```

Comment: Seem almost similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63408714/9193372)

Answer (score 0):

For **`Oracle`**, you can write this-

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT UNIQUE(city) FROM station WHERE
    LOWER(SUBSTR(city,1,1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
    INTERSECT  
    SELECT UNIQUE(city) FROM station WHERE
    LOWER(SUBSTR(city,LENGTH(city),1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE LOWER(LEFT(CITY,1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') AND LOWER(RIGHT(CITY,1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will work.

```
Select Distinct City from station
Where city Like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In **MSSQL server** code working fine

```sql
select distinct city from station where city like '[aeiouAEIOU]%[aeiouAEIOU]';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where substr(CITY,1,1)  in ('a','e','i','o','u') and substr(city,-1,1) in ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working in my case

```
select distinct(city) from station where city LIKE '%e' or city LIKE '%a' or city LIKE '%i' or city LIKE '%o' or city LIKE '%u';
```

Comment: 1st `distinct` is not a function. 2nd What does this answer add to all other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the query,

SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(CITY,'**^[aeiouAEIOU]**');

Answer (score -1):

As a beginner, this is how I solved it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city 
FROM station
WHERE
city LIKE 'a%' OR
city LIKE 'e%' OR
city LIKE 'i%' OR
city LIKE 'o%' OR
city LIKE 'u%';
```