# Find word with whitespace SQL pattern matching

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pattern-matching

I have a column with data `Oil 76072  KTC Vegetable (Plastic Drum)  20ltr`

and I want to check if `Veg` is available as a single word in the data. It can be first, last or a word in between like `KTC`

Query I have below returns data for `Veg` and `KTC` both.

```
SELECT
    Item,
    Description,
    SearchBox,
    Ranking,
    'Part Word Match' as SearchType 
FROM
    [HypEcommerce].[dbo].[ProductSearch]
WHERE (
    [searchbox] like '%_' + trim(ltrim('veg')) +'_%'
    OR [searchbox] like '%_'+ rtrim(ltrim('veg'))+ ''
    OR [searchbox] like ''+ rtrim(ltrim('veg')) +'_%'    
)
```

Comment: please tag the dbms being used.

Comment: I'm really not following, why can't you just do UPPER(searchBox) LIKE ' % VEG %'

Comment: What is the syntax for parsing words? Do you want all of the following to match: `'Veg out!'`, `'Living on the veg!'`, `'Squirrel (VEG) purple$'`, `'Version: X9.VEG;2.1'`, `'/Foods/Veg/Eggplant/Fried'`? The pattern might be `empty or non-alphanumeric`, `target string`, `empty or non-alphanumeric`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check if Veg is available as a single word in the dat

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Value VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('FooVeg Bar'), --not single word
('Foo Veg Bar'), --in the middle
('Veg Foo Bar'), --in the begining
('Bar Foo Veg'); --in the end
```

Since it can be anywhere, you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE LOWER(Value) LIKE '% veg %'
      OR
      RIGHT(LOWER(Value), 4) = ' veg'
      OR
      LEFT(LOWER(Value), 4) = 'veg '
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE Value LIKE '% veg %'
      OR
      Value LIKE '% veg'
      OR
      Value LIKE 'veg %'
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want:

```
WHERE ' ' + searchbox] + ' ' like '% ' + ' + trim(ltrim('veg')) + ' %'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 3 cases start, in the middle or at the end with `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT
    Item,
    Description,
    SearchBox,
    Ranking,
    'Part Word Match' as SearchType 
FROM
    [HypEcommerce].[dbo].[ProductSearch]
WHERE (
    [searchbox] like 'veg %' or 
    [searchbox] like '% veg %' or 
    [searchbox] like '% veg'    
)
```

I guess there would be other cases like `(veg ...)`.  
or using `LOWER([searchbox])` in case there is also `Veg` or `VEG`

Answer (score 0):

This would have been easy with a regular expression, unfortunately [SQL Server does not support regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server).

So you have to use `LIKE`, with the 3-branches test. I just updated your query to avoid the ulgy repeated `rtrim/ltrim` :

```
SELECT
    Item,
    Description,
    SearchBox,
    Ranking,
    'Part Word Match' as SearchType 
FROM
    [HypEcommerce].[dbo].[ProductSearch]
WHERE (
       veg like        [searchbox] + ' %' -- match at beginning
    OR veg like '% ' + [searchbox] + ' %' -- match in the middle
    OR veg like '% ' + [searchbox]        -- match at end 

);
```