# RegEx for replacing the tag elements in HTML for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

In a SQL Server database table, I have a column like this:

```
<p>Radio and television.</p><p>very popular in the world today.</p><p>Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small <span_style=":_black;">98.2%</span></p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. <span_style=":_black;">haha100%</span></p>
```

I want to delete the `<p>` and `</p>` and `<span_style=":_black;">` and `</span>` and all tag elements in HTML.

The text I ultimately want is like this：

```
Radio and television.very popular in the world today.Millions of people watch TV.That’s because a radio is very small 98.2% and it‘s easy to carry.haha100%
```

I want to do it with regular expressions. But, I can't find a regular expression to solve this problem.

What should I do?

Comment: That's what happens when system store data.

Comment: `replace` is about as good as it gets in SQL Server. Unless you write some CLR code.

Comment: It's designed to be stored with these tags.

Comment: Please clarify your question, in what language are you trying to remove these HTML tags?

Comment: What you want to do, and what is needed, can be two different things. [Parsing HTML with regex-es is stupid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/243373), and can never be done correctly in all cases. But don't let me stop you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a regular expression here, try to use the following:

```
DECLARE @html nvarchar(MAX) = N'<p>Radio and television.</p><p>very popular in the world today.</p><p>Millions of people watch TV. </p><p>That’s because a radio is very small <span_style=":_black;">98.2%</span></p><p>and it‘s easy to carry. <span_style=":_black;">haha100%</span></p>';

SET @html=REPLACE(@html,'span_style','span style') -- wrong tag

DECLARE @xml xml = @html

-- demo with variable
SELECT t.c.value('.','varchar(max)') AllText
FROM @xml.nodes('/') t(c)

-- demo with query
SELECT (SELECT t.c.value('.','varchar(max)') FROM q.xml_col.nodes('/') t(c)) AllText
FROM
  (
    -- your query with a xml-column is here
    SELECT CAST(@html AS xml) xml_col -- row 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(@html AS xml) xml_col -- row 2
  ) q
```

Comment: If the tag likes this:
<style type="text/css">
h1 {color:red}
p {color:blue}
.w1{width:30px}
</style>

Unable to list all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/lji9RP/1) might help you to do so:

```
 ((\<)[\w\/\=\x22\x27\:-;]+(>))
```

You only need to add any other chars that you may have in, such as <kbd>space</kbd>:

```
 [\w\/\=\x22\x27\:-;]
```

- You can simply replace <kbd>$1</kbd> with an empty string, using your codes.
- You might also consider other application-based requirement and language specific metachar escaping that you might have.
- You can also simplify this regex, if you wish:

[image]

About special chars, you might check for unicode/ASCII based on your [desired language](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlebcdic.html).

You can simply add it to the RegEx. For example, if you have special [quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark), you can update it similar to [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/kKSIQi/1/):

```
((\<)([\w\/\=\"\'\‘\:\’\-;\s]+)(>))
```

This RegEx is pretty simple to understand:

- It has a simple left boundary, <kbd><</kbd>, in a capturing group just to be safe

  ```
   ((\<)
  ```
- It has a simple right boundary: <kbd>></kbd>, in a capturing group just to be safe

  ```
   (>))
  ```
- It has a middle capturing group, where all your chars should be included:

  ```
   ([\w\/\=\"\'\‘\:\’\-;\s]+)
  ```

Then, it wraps up these three capturing groups in a group, which is not really necessary to do so, it is just to be safe, adding an extra boundary.

[image]

> I do not know about SQL Servers, but [this
>   post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server)
>   might help you to maybe design a query to do so.