# How do I use regex in loopback where clause - connected to a SQL Server datasource?

Tags: sql-server, loopbackjs

I am using the below code to search users in the SQL Server DB but it throws REGEXP error.

Using `loopback 3` and `loopback-mssql-connecter`

```
let searchedValue = await User.find({
        where: {
          or: [
            {first_name: new RegExp('\\b' + req.query.s, 'i')},
            {last_name: new RegExp('\\b' + req.query.s, 'i')},
            {email: new RegExp('^' + req.query.s, 'i')},
          ],
        },
      });
```

This exact query works when it is tied to a MongoDB datasource but doesn't work when using a SQL Server datasource.

I get the below errors

> Microsoft SQL Server does not support the regular expression operator
>   Unhandled error for request GET /api/leagues/searchusers/?s=nir:
>   RequestError: Incorrect syntax near 'REGEXP'.

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server [does not support regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server).  You can use `LIKE`, but no guarantees.

```
            {first_name: {like: '\\b' + req.query.s}},
            {last_name: {like: '\\b' + req.query.s}},
            {email: {like: '^' + req.query.s}}
```

MongoDB is a different datasource which does support them.

Comment: @marvin-irwin...Sorry for the delayed response. This approach did not work out. Any ideas on how I can implement a user search on a SQL Server Database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for SQL datasource

```
   [
        {first_name: { like: `%${req.query.s}%`} },
        {last_name: { like: `%${req.query.s}%`} },
        {email: { like: `${req.query.s}%`} },
   ]
```