# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Replace(System.String, System.String)' method

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have This Linq Query

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("[()\n-]");

return (from c in data.Table1
                    join cv in data.Table2 on new {c.ClientID, c.EmailAddress} equals new {cv.ClientID, cv.EmailAddress}                        
                    where (c.ClientID == clientid && pattern.Replace(c.CellPhone, "") == phone)
                    select cv.RecipientID).FirstOrDefault();
```

**I am replacing the special characters from the CellPhone. For instance, if Phone Cellphone number is (123)456-7890 I want number in 1234567890**

But I am getting this error :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Replace(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot
>   be translated into a store expression.

Comment: You cant use regular expressions directly in your query, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server

Comment: You're just reporting exception message here. What's the question?