# Retrieving data from table value parameter c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I haven't used TVP or stored procedures before and I'm hoping I can get some clarification on how to retrieve the equivalent of the first query as a dataset in c#. I created a custom type and procedure that seem to work and whenever I declare a variable and exec the stored procedure in SSMS it works, I'm just not sure how to replicate that in code.

```
SELECT ServLoc.ID, Meters.MeterID, MeterHistory.Stuff
FROM ServLoc 
INNER JOIN Meters ON ServLoc.ID = Meters.ServLocID
INNER JOIN MeterHistory ON Meters.MeterID = MeterHistory.MeterID
WHERE ServLoc.ID IN (1,2,3...40,000)



CREATE TYPE dbo.ServLocMeters 
AS TABLE (ServLocID int NOT NULL)


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ServLocMeters]
    @newServLocMeters ServLocMeters READONLY
AS
    SELECT ServLocID, Meters.MeterID, MeterHistory.Stuff
    FROM Meters 
    INNER JOIN MeterHistory ON Meters.MeterID = MeterHistory.MeterID
    WHERE ServLocID IN (SELECT ServLocID FROM @newServLocMeters)
    ORDER BY ServLocID


declare @table as ServlocMeters
insert into @table values (1)
insert into @table values (2)
insert into @table values (31)
exec sp_servlocmeters @table
```

Comment: Have you read the TVP [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server)? It has C# code examples.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: gotcha, thanks. and yes I have looked at the documentation but I've been struggling to find how to use the query with a dataadapter in c# (also link was incorrect) @DanGuzman

Comment: Sorry, this is the link I meant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

Comment: You would probably get better performance if your Table Type had a primary key `CREATE TYPE dbo.ServLocMeters AS TABLE (ServLocID int PRIMARY KEY);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an example shortly after, lol. Thanks marc for the prefix heads up.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("ServLoc");
table.Columns.Add("ServLocID", typeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
{
    table.Rows.Add(1 + i);
}

DataSet dbDatasets = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ServLocMeters", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter sqlParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newServLocMeters", table);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured; //tells ADO.NET we are passing TVP  
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    adapter.Fill(dbDatasets);
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the table type name, also the `ParameterDirection`. Better to add the parameter like this `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@newServLocMeters", SqlDbType.Structured) {TypeName = "dbo.ServLocMeters", Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = table});` You also need to dispose your adapter with `using`