# I want to write a function in Microsoft SQL Server to validate any UK Phone numbers and flag 1 if valid and flag 0 if invalid

Tags: regex, validation, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2019

This is my code:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[Vmobile](@mobileno VARCHAR(50))  
    --Returns true if the string is a valid mobile no.  
RETURNS bit  
AS
BEGIN  
     DECLARE @valid bit  

     IF @mobileno IS NOT NULL   
         SET @valid = 0  

     IF @mobileno like '^(?:0|\+?44)(?:\d\s?){9,10}$'     
         SET @valid=1  

     RETURN @valid  
END
```

The phone numbers can be in any UK format but it should support all UK Phone numbers.
E

```
g :
(415) 555-0132
+44 313314332
098 765 1234
+447975777666
07975777666
xxx-xxx-xxxx
01332 412251
01332 412 251
+44 1332 412251
```

where X can be any number.
Optional Plus can be allowed at first position only.
It should have 9 or 10 digit after zero if zero is entered in the beginning.
country code can be optional

Comment: Please explain what UK phone numbers look like, for the other 99.1% of the world (assuming that all UK inhabitants know all the different formats).

Comment: Is your code not working as you want it to? Throwing an error? Other?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added some examples . could you please check on that?

Comment: @Andrew I am getting 0 as flagged . Not working properly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using RegEx in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll have to start again.  You appear to be using a regular expression to test the phone number, and the SQL Server [LIKE operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#pattern-matching-by-using-like) does not afaik support regular expressions.

If you're using a DBMS that does support regular expressions, you'll have better luck getting a useful answer if you link to the regex documentation and, as @Gordon Linoff suggests, explain the pattern you're trying to match.  Also, please edit the tags *not* to mention SQL, because this functionality isn't defined by the SQL standard, and instead add the particular DBMS you're using.

Comment: I have reframed my question . I want to create a function in MS SQL Server 2019 to validate mobile numbers in UK. I have added some examples and my requirements.

Comment: Could you please help me with the like operator for my above requirements?