# Find all-numeric values in an alphanumeric field

Tags: sql

There is a name field which is set to alphanumeric in a table, the table is a very very large one. Is there a way to query the list where the name entered in this name field is all numeric?

The table name is `list`.
The filed name is `holder_name`.

I want to know if there are cases where the holder name is made up of entirely digits like 123456 and holds no letters.

I have tried using `like` but that didn't work.

Comment: What database product do you use?

Comment: To make it a little clearer, any solution to this is completely dependent on the RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression match:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   list
WHERE  holder_name ~ '^\d+$';  -- entirely digits
```

[PostgreSQL documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) (You didn't name your RDBMS.)

Answer (score 0):

Your previous tags suggest you used to use Oracle (and Oracle Forms); if that's still true, here are two options.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from list;

HOLDER
------
abc123
123456       --> this is the only value which consists of digits only
abcdef
12cd45
ab34ef
```

If it is still about Oracle Forms, depending on version you use you might find out that regular expressions won't work:

```
SQL> select holder_name
  2  from list
  3  where regexp_like(holder_name, '^\d+$');

HOLDER
------
123456
```

In that case, try `translate` function which works *everywhere* (in Oracle):

```
SQL> select holder_name
  2  from list
  3  where translate(holder_name, 'x0123456789', 'x') is null;

HOLDER
------
123456

SQL>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply.  It worked like a charm. Another question if i may, can you suggest any course etc that would help me getting skilled in MySQL, PLSQL and jn genrall?

Comment: I know Oracle offers various courses (and they are rather expensive). For anything else, I should Google for it but - that's what you can do yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This works for MySQL:

```sql
select holder_name
from list
where CAST(CAST(holder_name AS UNSIGNED) AS CHAR) = holder_name
```

see: [DBFIDDLE-MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/a9Ie0ZlP)

But needs some adaptations for MSSQL:

```sql
select holder_name
from list
where CAST(TRY_CAST(holder_name AS INTEGER) AS CHAR) = holder_name
```

see: [DBFIDDLE-MSSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/mlIMDUt3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [POSIX `regexp_like()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE) the exact same way in [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/DCkF9rxS), [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rs1Az_zV) and [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/4_tSvN-n):

```sql
SELECT * FROM list WHERE regexp_like(holder_name,'^[0-9]+$');
```

- the `[0-9]` meaning `[0123456789]` character class targets only digits
- `+` says there must be at least one character belonging to that digit class
- surrounding `^` and `$` say you don't want anything else in front or at the end

[The SQL standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization_history) specifies pattern matching, but as with everything it says, different RDBMS implement and call it differently, or even don't - satisfied with trading full compliance for performance, backward-compatibility or other reasons.

1. [(Microsoft) SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928413/5298879) requires an extension or UDF to do more than `LIKE` is capable of.
2. In [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators) there's a `regexp` function and operator declared but undefined until you do it.
3. [MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/QIMR9Yco) offers a predefined [`regexp`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp/).

---

> I want to know **if** there are cases where the holder name is made up of entirely digits like 123456 and holds no letters.

In general, checking *if* such cases [`exist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) can be carried out way faster than `count`ing *how many* there are, or fetching all such cases: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DsHGHURy)