# Record does not filtered properly in my DataGridView.

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

i have database like this:

[image]

And when i search the company name in the textbox with **"Jaya Raya Motor"** keyword, the result is like this:

[image]

But when i search the company name in the textbox with **"Jaya"** keyword, the result did not show anything.

I am confused, How is it possible? Because the first keyword is **"Jaya"**, and the full keyword is **"Jaya Raya Motor"**, it should show me the result, but now it is not.

How do i fix this?

Here is the code:

```
private void GetData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_choice.comboBox1.Text == "English")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                    _sound.Play();
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a character or more!", "Error");
                }

                else
                {
                    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        string query = "SELECT [ProductCode], [Quantity], [Description], [SubTotal], [Total], [IssuedBy], [To], [Times] FROM [TransRecord] WHERE [To] = @To ORDER BY [To]";

                        conn.Open();

                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@To", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                            cmd.Parameters["@To"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                            using (OleDbDataAdapter _adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
                                _ds.Clear();
                                _adapter.Fill(_ds, "TransRecord");
                                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                                dataGridView1.Refresh();
                            }

                            dataGridView1.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];
                            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help? Thank you!

Your answer will be great appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**  You are using `WHERE` clause  with equal `=` operator  to compare with Company Name.
if you use WHERE with equal operator it only returns the exact matching records.

**Solution:** you should use `LIKE` operator with wild card characters instead of equal operator for search functionality.

Try this:

```
string query = "SELECT [ProductCode], [Quantity], [Description], [SubTotal], [Total], [IssuedBy], [To], [Times] FROM [TransRecord] WHERE [To] LIKE @To ORDER BY [To]"; 
cmd.Parameters["@To"].Value = "%"+this.textBox1.Text+"%";
```

Comment: i have tried your code sir, but unfortunately i am getting an error, and the error says, `syntax error in FROM clause`

Answer (score 2):

You're just searching for a exact match. You may need to use `SubString` or `Like`.

Replace `WHERE [To] = @To` in your query by the following.

```
WHERE [To] LIKE LIKE % @To %
```

[Check this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505923/check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-sql-server-2005-using-a-stored-proced)

Answer (score 1):

You're using an equality operator:

`WHERE [To] = @To`

So, the string "Jaya" will never return results for records with a value of "Jaya Raya Motor". In this case you're looking for records that start with "Jaya". SQL support like queries: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp. It'll slow down your query and depending on the DB engine may or may not use the indexes you've defined for the field. But, it will produce the results you're expecting. You're looking for this:

```
WHERE [TO] like 'JAYA%'
```

Which will return all records where TO starts with "JAYA"