# find if there is a 6 digit number within a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would you advise to find out in Sql Server 2010/2012 if a query contains a substring equal to a 6 digits number?

e.g. "`agh123456 dfsdfdf`" matches the requirements

"`x123 ddd456`" doesn't match the requirements because the 6 digits are not consecutive

"`lm123`" doesn't match the requirements because only 3 digits are found (out of the required 6)

The problem I encountered so far: is that SUBSTRING as a function requires parameters  (position where the number presumably starts and this is random)
while PATINDEX returns the location of a pattern in a string, but we don't know the exact pattern (it can be any 6 digit number)

Any pointers or advice, much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I just thought of replacing digits by a character or a symbol like & and check if there is &&&&&& within the string. if there's a more elegant solution let me know please

Comment: By the way, do you know how to replace all digits at once within a single 'replace' function (so I don't have to use 10 'REPLACE' for each digit)? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove the 6 digit number from the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a string contains a substring in SQL Server 2005, using a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505923/check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-sql-server-2005-using-a-stored-proced)

Comment: How to find 6 or more numbers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms179859.aspx) operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Mycolumn LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: I think this will match 7 digits rather than 6.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai good spot! Obviously I was too eager with the Ctrl-V :)

Comment: @DavidG I corrected while you where answering Ankit :) Hoops I looked at history and I made the mistake. My bad, sorry

Comment: @DavidG : is it possible to use this syntax (or similar) in a replace statement ? Looks like someone want to hide information.

Comment: @bokan I don't think so, but you could do it with `PATINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`

Comment: @bokan Something like this `SUBSTRING(MyColumn, 0, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', MyColumn)) + SUBSTRING(MyColumn, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', MyColumn)+6, LEN(MyColumn))`

Comment: This will match numbers with **at least 6 digits**. If the user needs exactly 6 digits, you'll need to change the query.

Comment: @wdosanjos Indeed, unfortunately the OP is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

Even this should work.. considering you don't have a string like this

> abc123 abc123456

Try this

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max) = 'abcxyz123456'

SELECT ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@str,(SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@str)),6))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all rows in the table and mask the first 6-digit substring in each row:

```
DECLARE @mask varchar(max) = '######'
DECLARE @pattern varchar(max) = '%'+REPLACE(@mask,'#','[0-9]')+'%'

SELECT
  ISNULL(STUFF(col1,PATINDEX(@pattern,col1),LEN(@mask),@mask),col1)
FROM Table1
```