# T-SQL : Find 8 number digit in string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

I am trying to get first 8 digit number in string. For example, need to get 49691234  in all below strings. Tried to use PatIndex & Substring functions but not getting result I desire. Pls advise

Example:

```
'hello world # 49691234 - black fox'
'black fox # 49691234'
'black fox 49691234 hello'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions need a more specific example. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893714/find-if-there-is-a-6-digit-number-within-a-string, just use 8 instead of 6. read all answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find if there is a 6 digit number within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893714/find-if-there-is-a-6-digit-number-within-a-string)

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: And what happens when your number is not separated from other characters by a space? E.g., when you have "black fox #12345678"? If that number is important, then you should fix your schema and isolate it when the row is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `patindex()`:

```
select substring(col, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', col), 8),
from t;
```

Comment: Pure simple SQL, I love it!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [ngrams8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/).

```
-- sample data
declare @yourtable table(txt varchar(40));
insert @yourtable values
('hello world # 49691234 - black fox'),
('black fox # 49691234'),
('black fox 49691234 hello');

-- solution
select * 
from @yourtable t
cross apply dbo.NGrams8k(t.txt,8)
where token not like '%[^0-9]%';
```

**Results**

```
txt                                      position             token
---------------------------------------- -------------------- ----------
hello world # 49691234 - black fox       15                   49691234
black fox # 49691234                     13                   49691234
black fox 49691234 hello                 11                   49691234
```