# Parsing expression only with sql \ finding an order of expression's values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to find an order of words/letters inside an expression found in the database?

To be more clear here is an example:

From table X i'm getting the Names: "a" and "b".
In other table there is the expression: "b + a",
The result I need is b,1   |  a,2

Is there any way to do it using **only** SQL query?

P.S. I didn't find any reference to this subject...

Comment: what if a letter is repeated more than once in the same expression i.e. "b * (c + a) / (b - c)". how it is given numbers?

Comment: In that case i need the first time it was found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautiful question! Take a look at this solution wchich breaks expression into list of identifiers:

```
DECLARE @val varchar(MAX) = 'b * (c + a) / (b - c)';

WITH Split AS
(
    SELECT 1 RowNumber, LEFT(@val, PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', @val)-1) Val, STUFF(@val, 1, PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', @val), '')+'$' Rest
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RowNumber+1 Rownumber, LEFT(Rest, PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', Rest)-1) Val, STUFF(Rest, 1, PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', Rest), '') Rest
    FROM Split
    WHERE PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%', Rest)<>0
)
SELECT Val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(RowNumber)) RowNumber FROM Split
WHERE LEN(Val)<>0
GROUP BY Val
```

It yields following results (only first occurences):

```
b   1
c   2
a   3
```

If executed with `DECLARE @val varchar(MAX) = 'as * (c + a) / (bike - car)'` returns:

```
as      1
c       2
a       3
bike    4
car     5
```

Answer (score 1):

(From an similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505923/check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-sql-server-2005-using-a-stored-proced))

You can do it with [CHARINDEX()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) that searches for a substring within a larger string, and returns the position of the match, or 0 if no match is found.

```
CHARINDEX(' a ',' ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@mainString,'+',' '),'.',' ') + ' ')
```

Add more recursive REPLACE() calls for any other punctuation that may occur

For your question here is an example:

```
INSERT INTO t1 ([name], [index])
SELECT name, CHARINDEX(' ' + name + ' ',' ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('b * (c + a) / (b - c)','+',' '),'-',' '),'*',' '),'(',' '),')',' '),'/',' ') + ' ')
FROM t2
```

The result will be:

```
a, 10
b, 1
c, 6
```